# Rdf and java gui

Tags: java

I have a job to do and I want to display results from this program in my GUI but I just can not do it, then I want a method for allowing me to see the results of this program in my graph inetreface, so I created an interface and I reserved a button displays and an area for display (JTextArea), it means when I click on button shows me it shows the results (the contents of my Rdf file). I want your help if possible and thank you in advance

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    // use the FileManager to find the input file
    InputStream in = (InputStream) FileManager.get().open("C:/Users/SAMSUNG/Desktop/WICM2/projet/opus_august2007.rdf");
    if (in == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "File: " + "C:/Users/SAMSUNG/Desktop/WICM2/projet/opus_august2007.rdf"+ " not found");
    }
    // read the RDF/XML file
    model.read(in, "");

    // write it to standard out
    //model.write(System.out);
    model.write(System.out);
```

and here's my program interface

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.NodeIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

/**
 *
 * @author SAMSUNG
 */
public class frameFinal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form FrameFinal
     */
    public frameFinal() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setTitle("Rdf & taxonomie");
        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));

        jButton1.setText("PARCOURIR");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        jTextField3.setEnabled(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 327, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(79, 79, 79))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(120, 120, 120)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(157, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Chargement File", jPanel1);



        jButton3.setText("Visualise");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });



        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Visualiser", jPanel3);

        jButton4.setText("Generer");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);

        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(477, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(20, 20, 20))
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 271, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton3))
        );
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 489, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 570, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 246, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addGap(0, 25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Taxonomie", jPanel4);

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\SAMSUNG\\Desktop\\WICM2\\projet"));
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("RDF Definitions", "rdf", "RDF"));
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            this.jTextField3.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jTextField1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jTextField1ActionPerformed

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton4ActionPerformed
         jTextArea1.setText("");
         Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
          InputStream in = FileManager.get().open("C:/Users/SAMSUNG/Desktop/WICM2/projet/opus_august2007.rdf");
          Model m = model.read(in,null);
          NodeIterator nit = m.listObjects();
          List<String> lclass = new ArrayList<>();
          Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
           StmtIterator si = m.listStatements();
           while(si.hasNext()){
               Statement statement = si.next();
             if(statement.getPredicate().getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("subClassOf")){
                 String mere = statement.getObject().toString();
                 String fils = statement.getSubject().getLocalName();
                 if(map.containsKey(mere)){
                     List<String> l = map.get(mere);
                     l.add(fils);
                     map.replace(mere, l);
                 }else{
                     List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
                     l.add(fils);
                     map.put(mere, l);
                 }
             }
               if(statement.getObject().isResource() && statement.getPredicate().getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase("type")){
                   if(!lclass.contains(statement.getSubject().getLocalName())){
                     lclass.add(statement.getSubject().getLocalName())  ;
                   }
               }
           }
           jTextArea1.append("Les classes:\n");
           for(String classe:lclass){
               jTextArea1.append(classe+"\n");
           }
           jTextArea1.append("Les classe et les sous classes:\n");
           for(String l : map.keySet()){
               jTextArea1.append("Classe mere : "+l+"\n");
               for(String s:map.get(l)){
                   jTextArea1.append("   Classe fils:"+s+"\n");


               }
           }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton4ActionPerformed
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
        /*jTextArea2.setText("");
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        // use the FileManager to find the input file
        InputStream in =  FileManager.get().open("C:/Users/SAMSUNG/Desktop/WICM2/projet/opus_august2007.rdf");
        // DataInputStrean   st   =   new DataInputStream() ;
         if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "File: " + "C:/Users/SAMSUNG/Desktop/WICM2/projet/opus_august2007.rdf"+ " not found");
        }
        // read the RDF/XML file
        model.read(in, "");
        // write it to standard out
        //model.write(System.out);
      model.write(System.out);*/

    }   
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frameFinal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frameFinal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frameFinal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(frameFinal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new frameFinal().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: Ahmed: I fully understand that English may not be your first language, as it is not mine. But could you at least correct your typos and punctuation? It is really hard to analyze your question.

Comment: yes thank you very much for your comment, I'll try to improve my English

Comment: Ahmed: Thanks for improvements in punctuation; could you also try to change your code into a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (as advised in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to display entire RDF file in a text area. So if it's that what you want, you just need to read it in using a reader something like...

```
 try{
     FileReader f = new FileReader("c:\\opus_august2007.rdf");
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
    boolean eof = false;
    while(! eof)
      {
      String lineIn = b.readLine();
      if(lineIn == null)
        {
        eof = true;
        }
      else
        {
        mytxtarea.append(lineIn + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
      }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  you  very  much

Comment: Hello, I want to display my result of this program as a tree I want a hand to finish my work and thank you in advance
Here is my code